# Javascript SDK delete request issuing unexpected OAuthException

Tags: javascript, facebook, request

Using the code from the docs:

```
function deleteRequest(requestId) {
  FB.api(requestId, 'delete', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

I am returned an error:

> (#2) App Request Recipient Must Be Specified: The recipient for this app request must be specified through a user-signed access token or the fully specified app request ID.

I'm definitely connected to the FB REST before this, any thoughts?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to delete app requests with Javascript SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854918/how-to-delete-app-requests-with-javascript-sdk)

Answer (score 3):

if your app has migrated to Requests 2.0 efficient, than the requestId must contain both the apprequest id and the user id with _ between (because the same apprequest might be sent to multiple users)

for example:
apprequest=1111111 and 
user_id=2222222

then the requestId will be 1111111_2222222

```
function deleteRequest(appRequestId, userId) {
  FB.api(appRequestId+"_"+userId, 'delete', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the C# facebook SDK you can use this:

```
var fb = new FacebookClient(Config.FacebookAppId, Config.FacebookAppSecret);
var result = fb.Delete(string.Format("{0}_{1}?access_token={2}", facebookRequestId, facebookUserId, fb.AccessToken));
```

(see also this question: [Facebook Deleting Requests](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/13857108/facebook-deleting-requests/16790579))